# is it possible to slide in UIAlertView from left screen?

Tags: iphone, animation, uialertview

instead of popup from center can we change to another animation (eg, undo animation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just guessing here...

But you could place the UIAlertView within a scrollView and then animate the scroll view (such as when a UIPageControl is used).  The scrollView would be transparent except for the single UIAlerView placed on it.

Comment: it sound complex, and need to manage bounces of UIAlertView when move on the screen.
is it have another way?

Comment: Should not be to bad:

1) Add a scroll view that is 2X the width of the screen and big enough to hold the alert.
2) Add the alert to the scroll view on the far left.
3) Position the scroll view so it is off the screen.
4) use "scrollRectToVisible: animated:" to show the alert.

There may be a position (layering) aspect to worry about so the scroll view does not grab events.  So you might need to store the view below the others.  Or just don't add it to the parent view and hold it in reserve.